# Navigate using Primefaces Tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 and JSF 2.0.

In my application there is certain cases where a node selection should result in navigation. The problem is, it seems like the "nodeSelectListener" attribute is removed from Primefaces 3.2, forcing me to use ajax with the

```
<p:Tree ...>
 <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}" />
</p:Tree>
```

That only lets me navigate using

```
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(url);
```

which would be fine if it wheren't for the fact that the node selection is gone after navigation. The tree is inside a facelet template that is rendered on all pages.

My problem is that I cannot navigate using traditional JSF navigation, like returning a String i.e.: "myPage.xhtml" when using Ajax. That just will not work.

I've looked everywhere for a better solution to this, but I only find examples where the "nodeSelectListener" is used, setting ajax=false on the Tree. That is before 3.2 at least. 
Seems like it's hard to set the selected value programatically after the redirect too. Does anyone have a better solution?

Update: I've found a solution that works to some degree:

in the onNodeSelect method, I use this

```
FacesContext
  .getCurrentInstance()
  .getApplication()
  .getNavigationHandler()
  .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
          "null", "myPage.xhtml");
```

Comment: for navigation, there are separate ajax Event (expand, collapse). What is the problem you are facing in using select event is not stated. Can you please give more details

Comment: The problem is that I cannot navigate using JSF navigation (returning a String i.e "myPage.xhtml" because that will not work when using ajax. And when I'm using ExternalContext redirect, the Tree looses it's state when I get to the next page.

Comment: in onNodeSelect, you can get hold of tree node using event.getTreeNode(). Did you try using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(yourURL)

Comment: Yes, but as I described in the question I lost the state of  the Tree after the redirect.

Comment: @baron5, what scope is you tree managed bean?

Comment: My managed bean is SessionScoped. I've now abandoned the p:Tree, but I'm leaving this open in case there's somebody with an answer. Perhaps I'll be using this in a later project.